# Querying images from Sanity for GatsbyImage

Tags: graphql, gatsby, gatsby-image, sanity

I'm having trouble sourcing images from Sanity using the new `gatsby-plugin-image`. [The documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-source-sanity/) says to do the following:

```
import React from 'react'
import {getGatsbyImageData} from 'gatsby-source-sanity'
import {GatsbyImage} from 'gatsby-plugin-image'

const Person = ({data}) => {
  const imageData = getGatsbyImageData(data.sanityPerson.profileImage.asset)
  
  return <GatsbyImage image={imageData}/>
}

export default Person

export const query = graphql`
  query PersonQuery {
    sanityPerson {
      profileImage {
        asset
      }
    }
  }
`
```

However when I try and query the image asset, I get the following error:
[image: GraphQL error message]

My query looks like this:

```
export const query = graphql`
  query MyQuery {
    allSanityAbout {
      nodes {
        about_text
        about_image {
          alt
          image {
            asset
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

[The docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-image/) also say that "Any GraphQL File object that includes an image will have a `childImageSharp` field" but I can't work out how to query for it:
[image]

Here are the fields available inside the `image` node:
[image]

I get errors telling me `Cannot query field "childImageSharp"` on fields `SanityImage` or `SanityImageAsset` if I try and query for `childImageSharp` on the `image` or `asset` nodes.

Any pointers greatly appreciated!

Comment: What fields you have available inside  `image` node?

Comment: @FerranBuireu the issue is that for some reason GraphQL isn't returning 'childImageSharp', 'fluid' or 'fixed' fields for my image assets. New question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67041472/missing-fixed-and-fluid-fields-on-image-asset-with-gatsby-source-sanity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things changed a bit in the recent version of both Gatsby and Sanity. In their example, you can see that their `getGatsbyImageData` function is using the **asset** object directly object as parameter (and not using -> image -> asset like in the gatsby docs you are refering to).
There is no use for fluid or fixed in the GastbyImage in Gatsby V3.
In your case, you could try querying like this:

```
export const query = graphql`
  query MyQuery {
    allSanityAbout {
      nodes {
        about_text
        about_image {
          asset
          alt
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

Sending the return asset object to the sanity method `getGatsbyImageData` should work. Note how this method is getting the `image` parameter for you to use in GatsbyImage

```
...
  const imageData = getGatsbyImageData(data.sanityPerson.profileImage.asset)
  return <GatsbyImage image={imageData}/>
...
```

Comment: This doesn't work. For one thing, you can't query `asset` without child elements. It's crazy how out-of-date the docs are though!

Answer (score 1):

Getting Sanity and Gatsby to play nice is different. I was using the Wes Bos Mastering Gatsby but gatsby-image has changed since his video and this is how I got the latest Gatsby V3 GraphiQL API consuming an image from the Sanity GraphQL API

```
    import React from 'react'
    import { graphql } from 'gatsby'
    import { GatsbyImage, getImage } from 'gatsby-plugin-image'
    
    export default function AboutUsPage({ data }) {
      const { heading, image } = data.aboutUs
      const imagePlaceholder = getImage(image.asset)
    
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>About Us</h1>
          <GatsbyImage image={imagePlaceholder} alt={heading} />
          <p>{heading}</p>
        </div>
      )
    }
    
    export const query = graphql`
      query MyQuery {
        aboutUs: sanityAboutUs {
          heading
          image {
            asset {
              gatsbyImageData
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: This suggestion- using `gatsbyImageData` is the only solution I could find that worked for getting custom image types in Sanity with GraphQL, thanks.