# Missing 'fixed' and 'fluid' fields on image asset with `gatsby-source-sanity`

Tags: graphql, gatsby, gatsby-image, sanity

I'm trying to source images from Sanity with `gatsby-source-sanity` and `gatsby-image`. In the past I've had no issue querying the `fluid` image asset like so:

```
export const query = graphql`
  query {
    allSanityPicture {
      nodes {
        image {
          asset {
            fluid(maxWidth: 900) {
              ...GatsbySanityImageFluid
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

However, for some reason the `fluid` and `fixed` fields of `asset` aren't showing up in GraphQL:

[image: GraphQL fields]

There's definitely an image on the node, as the `url` field works.

I've installed and configured my Gatsby plugins as required:

```
plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-sanity`,
      options: {
        projectId: `mhlt1wid`,
        dataset: `production`,
        token: process.env.SANITY_TOKEN,
      }
    },
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
  ],
```

and deployed the GraphQL API with `sanity graphql deploy`.

What am I missing here? Have tried from scratch twice now on two fresh projects and still having the same issue.

Comment: It seems to be an open issue: https://github.com/sanity-io/gatsby-source-sanity/issues/114 (there are a lot of open threads) I know is not a solution but you can follow there the stack trace

Comment: Thanks @FerranBuireu, I've "solved" the issue for the time being by downgrading to an older version of Gatsby

Answer (score 1):

What version of Gatsby were you using when you wrote this and what version did you downgrade to?

The GraphQL query format for Gatsby 4 has changed along with the `gatsby-image` component being deprecated in favor of `gatsby-plugin-image`.

According to [this Gatsby article](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/release-notes/image-migration-guide/#api-changes) on migration, the older fragment-based method you use

```
   ...
     image {
      asset {
        fluid(maxWidth: 900) {
          ...GatsbySanityImageFluid
        }
      }
   ...
```

should be replaced in favor of the new syntax passing things like `layout` and `format` to the `gatsbyImageData()` resolver. The 'fluid' image type and 'maxWidth' have also been replaced with `CONSTRAINED` (in your case, or `FULL_WIDTH` if you want to just allow your  tag to set the width of the image) and `WIDTH` which is understood as a maximum width for constrained type images. So in Gatsby 4 using `gatsby-plugin-image` your code should look something like:

```
       ...
         image {
          asset {
            gatsbyImageData(layout: CONSTRAINED, width: 900)
          }
         }
       ...
```

[Here](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-plugin-image) is more information about the new component and API, and [here](https://dnlytras.com/blog/gatsby-images/) is a useful discussion of the new `CONSTRAINED` layout being used with `width` at the request.